# TreeView AfterExpand event sometimes don't work C#

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I have a TreeView and subscribed to the "TreeViewConnections_AfterExpand" and "" event.
everyone TreeNode contains MenuScript events. and the following code:

```
        //event
private void TreeViewConnections_AfterExpand(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
    {
        var activeKey = e.Node.ImageKey.Replace("Inactive", "Active");
        e.Node.ImageKey = activeKey;
        e.Node.SelectedImageKey = activeKey;
    }

//event
private void TreeViewConnections_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var currentNode = this.treeViewConnections.GetNodeAt(e.Location);
        if (currentNode == null) return;
        var currentBounds = currentNode.Bounds;
        Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle(currentBounds.Left - ExpandIcon.Width, currentBounds.Y, currentBounds.Width - 5, currentBounds.Height);
        if (bounds.Contains(e.Location)) return;
        this.treeViewConnections.SelectedNode = currentNode;

        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            SetupConnectionMenus(currentNode);
        }
    }

    private void SetupConnectionMenus(TreeNode node)
    {
        var isOpened = node.Nodes.Count > 0;
        if (node.ContextMenu == null)
        {
            var menu = new ContextMenuStrip();
            menu.Items.AddEx("Open Connection", node.Name + "_Open", !isOpened, onClick: OpenConnection_Click, context: node);
            menu.Items.AddEx("Close Connection", node.Name + "_Close", isOpened, onClick: CloseConnection_Click, context: node);
            node.ContextMenuStrip = menu;
        }
    }

   //event
   private void OpenConnection_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var menuItem = sender as ToolStripMenuItem;
        var currentNode = menuItem.Tag as TreeNode;
        OpenConnection(currentNode);
    }

    //event
    private void CloseConnection_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var menuItem = sender as ToolStripMenuItem;
        var currentNode = menuItem.Tag as TreeNode;
        currentNode.Nodes.Clear();
        currentNode.Collapse();
    }

private void OpenConnection(TreeNode node)
    {
        treeViewConnections.BeginUpdate();
        //add child node to  the node.
        treeViewConnections.EndUpdate();
        node.Expand(); //?????
    }
```

> TreeViewConnections_AfterExpand event sometime don't work. as shown in the figure:

[image]

But in this case, Is there something else I need to do?

Comment: Is node.Expand() is called every time you expect?

Comment: yes. every time call it, I hope it extended child nodes, and at the same time change the node icon

Comment: chang node icon in the "TreeViewConnections_AfterExpand" event .

Comment: Is it stops working after first expand?

Comment: first time it work. Later it won't work. i don't know why?

Comment: I suspect that second time you calling expand method you calling it for the incorrect node. Put some logging before node.Expand call and see if your node is correct.

Comment: node is correct. but i found "Tree Node" source code contain "IsExpanded" validation, IsExpanded value still "true" when node.Collapse

Comment: Oh, my God！ it is a question of method execution order. Try to adjust "CloseConnection_Click" in currentNode.Collapse () and currentNode.Nodes.Clear () order, it can work!!!!!!
TreeNode inner method "CollapseInternal",The conditions of the Collapse is the need to include the child nodes.

Comment: Reniuz, Thank you for your support!

Comment: [TreeNode class](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/TreeNode.cs,e47533e8b66cacd4,references)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is the cause of the Node.Collapse and Node.Nodes.Clear() invoke has caused problems.  the correct as following:

```
private void CloseConnection_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var menuItem = sender as ToolStripMenuItem;
        var currentNode = menuItem.Tag as TreeNode;
        currentNode.Collapse(); // Here will verify whether the current node has child nodes.
        currentNode.Nodes.Clear();
    }
```